# StateT newtype: switching from mtl to transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

with mtl, deriving MonadState seems to get make state operations properly lifted:

```
:set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
import Control.Applicative (Applicative)
import Control.Monad.Trans ( MonadIO, liftIO )
import Control.Monad.State (MonadState, evalStateT, modify, StateT, gets)

data State = State { int:: Int }
newtype St a = St { unSt :: StateT State IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState State)

let testLift = gets int >> return () :: St ()
```

for transformers, there is no MonadState

```
:set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict (runStateT, evalStateT, modify, StateT, gets)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class ( MonadIO, liftIO )
import Control.Applicative (Applicative)


data State = State { int:: Int }
newtype St a = St { unSt :: StateT State IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)


let testLift = gets int >> return () :: St ()
```

```
Couldn't match type `StateT State m0' with `St'
Expected type: St Int
  Actual type: StateT State m0 Int
In the return type of a call of `gets'
In the first argument of `(>>)', namely `gets int'
In the expression: gets int >> return () :: St ()
```

What am I supposed to be doing to make this work with transformers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're supposed to use `mtl` to make that work. `mtl` and `transformers` aren't really competitors -- `mtl` [depends on](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) transformers! It exists to to add classes like `MonadState` that use functional dependencies so they don't have to be part of the core (Haskell-98) type definitions. There's also a package (`monads-tf`) that uses type families instead, which is also compatible with `transformers` (but, really, you shouldn't use it).

Maybe I should be asking: Why are you "switching from mtl to transformers"?

Comment: I wanted to see if it was possible to remove the mtl dependency. But looks like MonadState requires it.

Comment: Yes, if you want `MonadState`-style classes, you'll need something like `mtl`. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

The `MonadState` instance is in package `monads-tf` or `monads-fd`, depending on whether you use type functions or functional dependences.  I tried it with `monads-tf` (because that's the package I prefer), and GHC wasn't able to derive a `MonadState` instance for `St`, so you'll have to write one yourself.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -package transformers -package monads-tf -hide-package mtl #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict (runStateT, evalStateT, modify, StateT)
import Control.Monad.State.Class  -- MonadState class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class ( MonadIO, liftIO )
import Control.Applicative (Applicative)

data State = State { int:: Int }
newtype St a = St { unSt :: StateT State IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

instance MonadState St where
  type StateType St = State
  get = St get
  put x = St (put x)
```

Comment: If you'd use monads-fd, the deriving would work: `deriving (MonadState State, ...)`

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong, but was getting `StateType' is not a (visible) associated type of class `MonadState'. So monads-fd is marked as obsoleted and I should use mtl

Comment: `StateType` is part of `monads-tf`, which competed with `monads-fd`. But `monads-fd` is now obsolete and replaced with `mtl`.